# Does bouncing my connection through personal computers or phones prevent detection?

Tags: uplink

Since you can't connect to personal computers and phone numbers and look at their logs does that mean after bouncing through them I wouldn't be able to be traced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Ultimate Uplink Guide](http://guide.modlink.net/index.php), section 1.4:

> Remember, everywhere keeps logs, including Voice Phone Systems. Just
>   because you can't get to the logs, it doesn't mean they aren't there.

So no, bouncing through a phone or personal computer (or public access terminal) will not remove the risk of being passively traced.

Comment: Bouncing your connection will slow traces down. If you pass through a system that you have administration access to you can remove your tracks.